# fs.createReadStream not triggering with Jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am working with fs.createReadStream to read the file. When executing the function from the file it's working, triggering the events(data, end).
I need to write some unit tests, but when calling the function. It didn't hit any of the events(data, end). I don't understand the reason.

The original issue I am working on is downloading files from a response. To isolate I created the file_func.ts file.

```
const response = await fetch(fileUrl);
if (!response.ok) {
  throw new Error(response.statusText);
}

const dest = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
response.body.pipe(dest);
response.body.on("finish", async function () {
});
```

Environment
Node v18.16.0

Typescript: Version 4.9.5 (using as node module)

file_func.ts

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import path from "path";

const fileName = "./tests/sample.txt";
const dirPath = path.join(__dirname, fileName);
export async function working() {
  var data = '';

  var readerStream = fs.createReadStream(dirPath); //Create a readable stream

  readerStream.setEncoding('utf8'); // Set the encoding to be utf8.

// Handle stream events --> data, end, and error
  readerStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log('data');
    data += chunk;
  });

  readerStream.on('end',function() {
    console.log('end');
    console.log(data);
  });

  readerStream.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
  });

  console.log("Program Ended");
}

working();
```

Result:

```
t@GTKNZ072:~/Project/pl/functions/a$ ts-node file_func.ts 
Program Ended
data
end
This is a test file
Another line
```

**Unit test file**

```
import {working} from "../file_func";

it("Test read files", async () => {
  await working();
});
```

Unit test result

```
console.log
    Program Ended

      at working (functions/a/file_func.ts:28:11)

  console.log
    Program Ended

      at working (functions/a/file_func.ts:28:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

1. Because you are calling `working();` inside your module, the `working` function will be called **twice** during the tests: first time when importing the module (due to the `working()` call mentioned earlier) and second time in your test `await working();`. This is the reason you see the `Program Ended` log twice.
2. Just because you made `working` async it doesn't mean it will function as you expect it to. Node will still wait for all stream operations to finish so your code should work in theory, but that will happen after `Program Ended` was executed. This is what I get when running `tsx` and use [NodeJS Test runner](https://nodejs.org/api/test.html):

```bash
elvis@elvis-ThinkPad-T480s:~/plm$ ./node_modules/.bin/tsx test.js 
Program Ended
Program Ended
✔ Test read files (0.80028ms)
data
data
end
some test data
end
some test data
```

What you want to do instead is add a `Promise` around the streamer code like this:

```js
export async function working() {
  try {
    const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var data = "";

      var readerStream = fs.createReadStream(dirPath); //Create a readable stream

      readerStream.setEncoding("utf8"); // Set the encoding to be utf8.

      // Handle stream events --> data, end, and error
      readerStream.on("data", function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
      });

      readerStream.on("end", function () {
        resolve(data);
      });

      readerStream.on("error", function (err) {
        reject(err.stack);
      });
    });

    console.log(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Got error", err);
  } finally {
    console.log("Program Ended");
  }
}
```

This will now make the `await working();` to do what it is intended to do and will print

```bash
elvis@elvis-ThinkPad-T480s:~/plm$ ./node_modules/.bin/tsx test.js 
some test data
Program Ended
some test data
Program Ended
✔ Test read files (4.357794ms)
```

*Note: I also removed the `console.log('data')` and `console.log('end')`.*

Comment: Keep in mind you should use `let` and `const` instead of `var`. And, also, I haven't fixed the call to `working()` inside your module so it is still printing things twice as per my point 1.